# BeautifulSoup is HTML escaping strings which have escaped characters

Tags: python, escaping, beautifulsoup, html-escape-characters

I am reading a string from file:

```
a = '<script>closedSign: \'<img src="/static/images/drop-down.png" style="margin-top: -3px;"  />\'</script>'
```

Now, when I run

```
BeautifulSoup(a)

<script>closedSign: '&lt;img src="/static/images/drop-down.png" style="margin-top: -3px;"   /&gt;'</script>
```

Thus, `<img` is being HTML escaped into `&lt;img`

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Avoid what? What do you want to achive?

Comment: Just edited the Question to explain it better.

Also, just noticed this problem happens only on BeautifulSoup3.2.1 and not on 3.2.0

Comment: It sounds like you've run into this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/949074

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use BeautifulSoup 3.2.0 instead of 3.2.1 to fix this problem.

Comment: Fixed the problem for me too. Thanks a lot for the solution and -1 for BeautifulSoup breaking such a thing after a minor update.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the "Entity Conversion" section of the [Beautiful Soup Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html).

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
```

Comment: Paulo,
convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES works on strings which are already HTML escaped.
Example: to return < img from parsing & lt;img
But here the problem is, parsing itself is returning a HTML Escaped string.

I hope I was able to clearly explain my problem.

Comment: What happens if you run BeautifulSoup a second time over the script tag HTML?

Comment: For possile `bs4` users: `convertEntities` [doesn't](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#entities) exist anymore in bs4.