# Python Beautifulsoup: < and > become &lt; and &gt;

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am doing some web scraping using beautifulsoup4.

However, half of the website gets scrambled by `<` and `>` being replaced with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. ***What am I doing wrong? Why does beautifulsoup do this?*** The point at which the html turns to gibberish isn't always the same (the website's contents can change every other minute).

This is my code:

```
import requests, bs4

url = 'https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-kiel/wohnung/k0l663r10'
agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}
r= requests.request('GET', url, headers=agent)

file = open('response.txt', 'w')
file.writelines(r.text)
file.close()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())

file = open('soup.txt', 'w')
file.writelines(soup.prettify())
file.close()
```

`Soup.txt` failed after 1209 lines because of a Unicode character that couldn't be encoded (error-message is at the end of `console-output`). That's before the gibberish. Line `1683` in `console-output` is where stuff begins to be messy.

Comment: None of your pastebin links work. Please post relevant information in the post here, not at external sites.

Comment: Try to add an encoding: `file = open('soup.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')`. This works for me. Edit: But it doesn't fix the "&lt;" problem. :(

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291500/beautifulsoup-is-html-escaping-strings-which-have-escaped-characters help you? It seems to be a problem with BeatifulSoup escaping html.

Comment: @BlackBeans Thats about a problem with beautifulsoup 3.2.0. I am using 4.10.0. 
I will try to see if using another version will help tho.

Comment: I just tried it with `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')` and the "&lt;" problem is gone. Caveat: I didn't check if there are new problems now.

Comment: @BlackBeans I couln't install 3.2.0. I tried 4.9.3 instead. Using that, beautifulsoup still produces faulty html.

Comment: @codingmonkey idk if you saw but on that post there was an other solution that changing version, that is, doing `BeatifulSoup(r.text, convertEntities=BeatifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)`. Maybe that could help too (as parsing HTML as XML might cause other issues that are yet unknown).

Comment: ~~BeatifulSoup~~ BeautifulSoup